# Can my CurrentThreadID ever change?

Tags: multithreading, winapi

Is it possible for the thread that is running a section of code to change during that code block?

I am specifically thinking of code running inside ASP.net, where methods are executed against the Thread Pool.

If my code initiates an I/O operation (e.g. database) the execution is suspended pending the completion of an I/O completion port. In the meantime, that thread-pool thread can be re-used to handle another web request.

When my I/O completes, and my code is returned to a thread-pool thread - is it guaranteed to be the same thread?

E.g.

```
private void DoStuff()
{
   DWORD threadID = GetCurrentThreadID();

   //And what if this 3rd party code (e.g. ADO/ADO.net) uses completion ports?
   //my thread-pool thread is given to someone else(?)
   ExecuteSynchronousOperationThatWaitsOnIOCompletionPort(); 

   //Synchronous operation has completed

   threadID2 = GetCurrentThread();
}
```

Is it possible for

```
threadID2 <> threadID
```

?

i mentioned the .NET Thread Pool, but there is also the native thread pool. And i have written code for both.

Is it ***ever*** possible for my **`ThreadID`** to be ripped out from under me? Ever.

## Why do i care?

The reason i care is because i'm trying to make an object thread-safe. That means that sometimes i have to know which so-called *"thread"* of execution called the method. Later, when they return, i know that "they" are still "them".

The only way i know to identify a *"series of machine instructions that were written to be executed by one virtual processing unit"* is through `GetCurrentThreadID`. But if `GetCurrentThreadID` changes; if my series of machine instructions can be moved to different *"virtual processing units"* (i.e. threads) during execution, then i cannot rely on `GetCurrentThreadID`.

Comment: You can't get such a guarantee, custom CLR hosts are allowed to implement threads the way they see fit.  The threadpool is also a customizable item.  Sure, you'll get away with it.  Today anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no. No synchronous function would do this.

With sufficient cleverness and evil you could create a function that did this. However, you would expect it to break things and that's why nobody actually does this.

As just the most obvious issue -- what happens if the calling thread holds a lock for the duration of the synchronous call?